# Write to Plist key value per item, from UITableView UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, plist

I have a `UITableView`, populated from an `NSMutableDictionay` by way of an editable plist, not located in main bundle.  I can read/write/add to the plist.

The `UITableView` has `UISwitches`. The plist is root/dictionary with 6 root keys, each containing 4 items,,

my keys are (example)

```
theball     Array    (4 items)
  item 0    string   stringxssd
  item 1    string   stringgad
  item 2    string   stringgad
  item 3    string   stringrad
theswitch   Array    (4 items)
  item 0    Boolean  NO
  item 1    Boolean  YES
  item 2    Boolean  NO
  item 3    Boolean  NO
```

When a user turns a switch on/off YES/NO. how can I write to the plist and change just the / lets say item 2 of `theswitch` key, boolean value to `YES`? So far i cannot alter the boolean value for a keys item specifically, just the key itself? I want to change each item per switch change...

Comment: Did you tried anything ? Please add any code that you tried for achieving this. We can help to find out the issue, in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
[myDictionary setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: switch.isOn ] forKey:@"someKey"];
```

and unpack it like this

```
BOOL someBool = [[myDictionary objectForKey: @"someKey"] boolValue ];
```

so try a switch action something like this..

```
-(IBAction) switchAction:(id)sender{

NSInteger swNum = [sender tag];
UISwitch swtch = (UISwitch *)sender;
BOOL theSetting = swtch.isOn;

//assuming a NSMutableDictionary property which was loaded from plist file at launch
//let us call this dictionary self.model  ..

NSArray *theBooleans = [self.model objectForKey: @"theswitch" ];
NSMutableArray *boolsMutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: theBooleans ];
[boolsMutable replaceObjectAtIndex:swNum withObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool:theSetting]];

[self.model setObject:boolsMutable forKey: @"theswitch" ];
}
```

Comment: Im sorry it appears that way to you.  I wonder why you supplied an answer given your own extremely limited understanding. Are you also an ass who is just after points?  Please try to avoid calling people names.  ps. I would not have made an entry if I considered yours to be of any quality. (or if you went and edited it after having its flaws pointed out to you).  The best :)

Comment: For the record, I don't know where you get your idea that a BOOL to NSNumber is cheaper than BOOL to integer -  or that a conversion statement is cheaper than a simple if and set -  I'll be upfront with you - I don't know either - what you say remains to be proven.  Changing the setting is a once in a blue moon thing, although reading it maybe once  every time an app is opened - in other words - its not a big deal.

Comment: Jef, you hit it on the nail, with a lil modification. I added another key called switch tags, now each row's switch has a tag related to their corrisponding relation to the cell.

Answer (score 0):

For those that were interested. Thanks to Jef, I utilized his code with the ibaction call which i already had....,

```
-(IBAction) switchAction:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"*MVC* switchAction ");
    NSInteger swNum = [sender tag];
    Switches = (UISwitch *)sender;
    BOOL theSetting = Switches.isOn;

    NSArray *theBooleans = [self.TheDict objectForKey: @"UserSwitch" ];
    NSMutableArray *boolsMutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: theBooleans ];
    [boolsMutable replaceObjectAtIndex:swNum withObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool:theSetting]];

    [self.TheDict setObject:boolsMutable forKey: @"UserSwitch" ];
    [TheDict writeToFile:PlistLocation atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"*MVC* switchAction COMPLETE");

}
```

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath the switches are generated as the table is built and the switchs are givin a tag from the plist.

```
NSNumber *tagNumber = [SwitchTag objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger blabla = [tagNumber integerValue];
// add the switchs
    Switches = nil;
    Switches = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    Switches.tag = blabla;
    NSLog(@"*MVC* Switches.tag: %d", blabla);
    cell.accessoryView = Switches;
    BOOL switchState;
    switchState = [[theSwitch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    if (switchState == TRUE)
    {
        [Switches setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [Switches setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
    [Switches addTarget:self action:@selector(switchAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

.. Jef, your the man. Thanks for the clue,code, and speedy answer.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot save boolean values to a plist it need to be an integer or a string  I use this code directly from the IBOutlet UISwitch variables:

```
     [plistDict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",UI_swictch1.on] forKey:@"UI_switch"];
```

This updates the NSMutable Dict - of course you need to write the plist back as a file and I assume you have the code for that.  I assume you know how to do the rest.

Comment: It's kind of an unusual practice to store boolean values in `NSString` form like that (although it obviously works).  most of the time, you see them converted to `NSNumber`s.  In fact, with literal syntax, it can just be `@(UI_switch1.on)` -- unboxing is also easy with `[myNSNumberObject boolValue]`

Comment: I've used that code for years since IOS 5 and it works, in all these years I haven't tried your suggested way maybe next time  ....   One comment though, the item is going to be stored as a string not as an NSNumber construct so the simplest way to unbox is an if statement (the value is either nil, 1 or 0).

Comment: It does not need to be 'an integer or a string'. It needs to be: NSArray*, NSDictionary*, NSDate*, NSData*, NSNumber* or NSString*  In my opinion this is a poor answer.  setValue: forKey:  is not appropriate, you want setObject: forKey:  furthermore storing a BOOL to an NSString (when NSNumber is available to you) is poor design, regardless how long when you've been doing it, sorry

Comment: Jef you are right, plist already support  bool in NSNumber and all the other formats you mentioned,  Haven't change the code or read about plist docs for sometime, If I remember correctly the first time I coded this there was some restriction in coding NSNumber in files.     One more thing - I regularly load plist from excel csv files which are essentially in string format - that would eliminate the other format of data wouldn't it?